# Accessing wire/reg dimensions in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

In VHDL there are many predefined attributes that can help in making code more generic, e.g.:

```
signal sig : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  
-- ...  
for i in sig'range loop ...
```

Is there a similar way to access the dimensions of a Verilog `wire` or `reg`?

Of course it's possible to define the boundaries of each `wire` or `reg` as a parameter as in:

```
parameter w_upper = 7;  
parameter w_lower = 0;  
wire [w_upper:w_lower] w;
```

but that seems like a lot of overhead and far less elegant than VHDL.

I have seen that SystemVerilog has things like `$bits`, `$size`, `$high` and `$low`, but what about Verilog-2005 or earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Verilog-2005 doesn't have equivalents for VHDL attributes (`'size`, `'left`, `'right`, `'high`, `'low`, etc.).

As you mentioned in your question, that feature was introduced in SystemVerilog, where you have following attributes:
`$dimensions`, `$unpacked_dimensions`, `$left`, `$right`, `$low`, `$high`, `$increment`, `$size`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But how did engineers achieve generic/parameterizable code before? Is the example I gave in my question a common way this is done by convention?  I come from the world of VHDL and coding without any built-in support for generic code feels quite odd ;-)

Comment: @damage Typically Verilog uses a single parameter to define the width of all relevant signals and any generated code (`paramter WIDTH = 8; reg [WIDTH-1:0] a; ... generate for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i = i + 1) ...`). However, its better to have functions like `$bits`, `$size` and `$clog2`, so they added them to make it easier and more generic in SV :)